# Share an image to specific apps

Tags: android, eclipse, android-image

I want to show a dialog with specific apps list and want to share my picture along with text message.

Something like this but I want to add only few e.g `Facebook` and `Twitter`.

How can I do that?

[image: My Image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think to achieve this you need to create your own Alert Dialog with specific application, and share picture with that specific application when user click on it.

**Edit :**  `sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");`   `// for plain text`

```
     sharingIntent.setType("image/jpeg");   // For Jpeg Image
```

> It is possible to target specific applications using the “setType”
>   method, but this can be a risky strategy, potentially causing problems
>   if the user does not have those particular apps installed. By keeping
>   the sharing function as generic as possible, you give your users
>   control over how they want to share your content. Sticking to the
>   standard behaviour for sharing in Android applications also creates an
>   intuitive user experience.

**Edit :** [Look Here](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-implement-a-share-intent/) for Example .

Comment: How will I make a popup like this, a popup that will get all the apps list?

Comment: Thanks for all this. Just one last thing, can text with image both at a time can be send? like facebook, twitter, etc? using this way?

Answer (score 0):

i think you make your custome dialog to share item, 
or this may helps you

```
                Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                shareIntent.setType("application/bluetooth");
                // here use specific type of Application    
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share with"));
```